# the efficiency compare between gevent and thread

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent

Recently,I'm working on a gevent demo and I try to compare the efficiency between gevent and thread. Generally speaking，the gevent code should be more efficient than the thread code. But when I use time command to profile the program, I get the unusual result(my command is `time python FILENAME.py 50 1000`,the last two parameters means pool number or thread number,so I change the two number in the table below). The result shows that the thread is more efficient than the gevent code,so I want to know why this happen and what's wrong with my program? Thanks.

gevent VS thread

[image]

My code is below(The main idea is use thread or gevent to send multi HTTP request):

******This is the thread version code******

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")
import requests
import threading
import time
import urllib2

finished = 0


def GetUrl(pagenum):
    url = 'http://opendata.baidu.com/zhaopin/s?p=mini&wd=%B0%D9%B6%C8&pn=' + \
        str(pagenum*20) + '&rn=20'
    return url


def setUrlSet():
    for i in xrange(requestnum):
        urlnum = i % 38
        urlset.append(GetUrl(urlnum))


def GetResponse(pagenum):
    try:
        r = requests.get(urlset[pagenum])
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    pass


def DigJobByPagenum(pagenum, requestnum):
    init_num = pagenum
    print '%d begin' % init_num
    while pagenum < requestnum:
        GetResponse(pagenum)
        pagenum += threadnum
    print '%d over' % init_num


def NormalThread(threadnum):
    startime = time.time()
    print "%s is running..." % threading.current_thread().name
    threads = []
    global finished, requestnum
    for i in xrange(threadnum):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=DigJobByPagenum, args=(i, requestnum))
        threads.append(thread)
    for t in threads:
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
        finished += 1
    endtime = time.time()
    print "%s is stop.The total time is %0.2f" % \
        (threading.current_thread().name, (endtime - startime))


def GetAvageTime(array):
    alltime = 0.0
    for i in array:
        alltime += i
    avageTime = alltime/len(array)
    return avageTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threadnum = int(sys.argv[1])
    requestnum = int(sys.argv[2])
    print 'threadnum : %s,requestnum %s ' % (threadnum, requestnum)
    originStartTime = time.time()
    urlset = []
    setUrlSet()
    NormalThread(threadnum)
```

******This is the gevent verison code******

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import gevent
from gevent import pool
import requests
import time

finished = 0


def GetUrl(pagenum):
    url = 'http://opendata.baidu.com/zhaopin/s?p=mini&wd=%B0%D9%B6%C8&pn=' + \
        str(pagenum*20) + '&rn=20'
    return url


def setUrlSet():
    for i in xrange(requestnum):
        urlnum = i % 38
        urlset.append(GetUrl(urlnum))


def GetResponse(url):
    startime = time.time()
    r = requests.get(url)
    print url
    endtime = time.time()
    spendtime = endtime - startime
    NormalSpendTime.append(spendtime)
    global finished
    finished += 1
    print finished


def GetAvageTime(array):
    alltime = 0.0
    for i in array:
        alltime += i
    avageTime = alltime/len(array)
    return avageTime


def RunAsyncJob():
    jobpool = pool.Pool(concurrent)
    for url in urlset:
        jobpool.spawn(GetResponse, url)
    jobpool.join()
    endtime = time.time()
    allSpendTime = endtime - originStartime
    print 'Total spend time is %0.3f, total request num is %s within %s \
            seconds' % (allSpendTime, finished, timeoutNum)
    print 'Each request time is %0.3f' % (GetAvageTime(NormalSpendTime))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    concurrent = int(sys.argv[1])
    requestnum = int(sys.argv[2])
    timeoutNum = 100
    NormalSpendTime = []
    urlset = []
    urlActionList = []
    setUrlSet()
    originStartime = time.time()
    RunAsyncJob()
```

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere.

Comment: sorry for my text,I'll improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gevent.monkey.patch_all(httplib=True)
```

It seems that by default gevent does not patch *httplib* (have a look at http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html : `httplib=False`) so you are actually doing blocking requests and you lose all advantages of the asynchronous framework. Although I'm not sure whether *requests* uses *httplib*.

If that doesn't work, then have a look at this lib:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Comment: Hi @freakish ,I add the `httplib=True` and I got this exception `gevent.httplib is no longer provided, httplib must be False`

Comment: gevent provides own clone of httplib, called `gevent.httplib`. it does not need to be monkey-patched anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Re: `httplib=False`

You are already using `requests` library to make web calls. It has `gevent` flavour called `grequests`:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Overall I don't immediately see much reason to prefer one style of threading to the other, if your pool is so small. Of course real threads are relatively heavy (start with 8MB stack), but you have to take that into proportion to the size of your job.

My take, try both (done), verify you are doing both right (to do) and let numbers do the talking.

Comment: Thanks.I have tried the `grequests` and it can't request too much at one time.

Comment: btw., pycurl's "multi" interface allows you to trigger as many requests as you want from a single thread. http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/curlmultiobject.html the documentation is not most useful, but it rocks when it comes to performance.